# The electric field inside the shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

If we place a $+q$ charge in the center of a spherical shell, what is the electric field inside the shell?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Charge will distribute itself over the outer surface of the shell making the electric field inside the shell equal to zero.